# How can I use decode to merge IF ELSE in Oracle. Required for code re-usability

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, decode

It is something like this:

```
if xyz = a then
    select col1 from tab1
    where w1, w2;
else
    select sum (col1) from tab1
    where w1, w2, w3;
endif;
```

Comment: You're asking how to do an IF flow control in PL/SQL?

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why `decode` specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really put this logic into a single query.  You can use `union all` though:

```
select col1
from tab1
where w1, w2 and (xyz = a)
union all
select sum(col1)
from tab1
where w1, w2, w3 and (xyz <> a)
having (xyz <> a);
```

Comment: Thank you!I have a few doubts though- (1). Wouldn't that impact performance because select is getting executed even if xyz <>a , in the first part? (2)- Query still has to be written twice with added w3 condition? (3) Are you sure result set would be same? Lets say if xyz=a fails but since it is in union with xyz<>a then so it will hinder the execution of later part right ? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when xyz = a then (select col1 from tab1 where w1, w2)
                         else (select sum(col1) from tab1 where w1, w2, w3)
            end [as <column_alias>]
from   dual
;
```

Comment: This will only work if the first select always returns exactly one row

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - right... I thought the OP meant to asasign the result to a variable and meant to ask him if he knows for sure the first query will return exactly one row! But then I forgot - it was late in the day... Good point, thanks!